# Is this an Inverted sentence and what does this mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> How lockdowns ease will itself affect the scale of economic damage.

Here is my understanding:
How does the ease of lockdowns will affect the economic damage?

Please correct me if it’s wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sentence is not a question. **"How"** here means **"the way or manner in which"** (entry two at [this link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/how)).

So the sentence means "The way in which lockdowns ease will affect the scale of economic damage."

Answer (score 1):

"How lockdowns ease" means "the manner in which lockdowns ease"

So it's saying that this manner will be a factor influencing the economic damage.